# How can i add Comment section for each Field-collection sections?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

How can i add Comment section for each Field-collection sections ?

I have Step1, Step2,... etc.

Now user want to add comment for any steps.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you can do this with entity reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://drupal.org/project/field_comments on the field of the field collection.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: At the moment it doesn't work with the above module, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2338593